# resolving a formula that may be calling something in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Received quite a bit of help to create this project so I'm reverse engineering the parts I want to change or fix. I typically match the adjacent cells and just change the column letter. For some reason this part is outputting an error saying "Empty Array".

Shown cell matches the columns to the right in the formula at the top. I am correctly referrencing the name of a different sheet but an error still comes up. The step into doesn't seem to work properly(it doesn't show my location on the actual excel document) and I'm not sure where to look to resolve "Empty Array". I am sure it's a simple fix, so any help would be appreciated, just let me know if i need to provide more info.

ReferenceSheet(EmptyArray)

[image]

I am correctly referrencing the name of a different sheet but an error still comes up. The step into doesn't seem to work properly(it doesn't show my location on the actual excel document) and I'm not sure where to look to resolve "Empty Array".

Comment: Can you share the relevant VBA as well?

Comment: Looks like you are using names in your references like `seq` and similar. Are you sure those names are properly referenced? Besides, your input string for INDIRECT looks something like `Data!seq1:seq1000000` and that makes no sense...